# When is exceeded reputation cap awarded

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Sorry if this question has already been asked.

Let me explain the situation:

Last night I capped the daily rep limit, I was still able to receive reputation for answered question of course, but up votes did not show which I understood ( i was able to see the up votes on my post but no reputation was given).

Today expecting to see my last night accumulated reputation points I only saw the reputation from up votes earned today.

So my question:

When will exceeded reputation ( that above the daily cap of 200) be awarded?

Comment: Never. That's the point of a cap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be awarded 'missed' reputation from upvotes received after you have hit the cap.

I think you misunderstood the reputation cap, upvotes after you reached the cap do not earn you reputation *at all*. You earn reputation for upvotes the next 24 hour period until you hit the cap again, but not for votes received during the cap period.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp To help other people solve their problems, which is why you should be here in the first place, rather than to increase some arbitrary number next to your name.

Comment: +1 wow, this is new. Than what is the point of answering after you have reached your cap?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp to help people

Comment: @servy fair enough but it was a hard eraned number next to my name of 150 ( alot for me :P) thanks though that cleared it up. will accept when I can

Comment: @DavidKroukamp The "real" purpose of the repcap is to keep you coming back everyday so you don't "miss out" on any rep.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Even if you don't get rep, you get points leading to shiny badges.

Comment: @dystroy so I see, at least or I would really begin to question the rep capping

Comment: Without rep caping, we wouldn't be able to compete on the month or quarter ranking with old players like John Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

It will never be awarded. You can only earn 200 rep per day plus extra points for bounty and accepted answers. The rest is lost.

Comment: +1 thank you never knew this but i find it strange why than would anyone want to answer after they have capped the daily limit?!

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: to earn the accept scores. And to help out of course. Bounties and accept scores (both the +15 from accepted answers and the +2 from accepting an answer on a question of your own) still count beyond the cap.

Comment: And after 200 rep maybe somebody will spend the rest of the day in real life

Comment: Thank you now I get it

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: On SO, I have earned [335 points so far today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation). The 135 points over the 200 limit are from 9 accepted answers. Apparently that's enough motivation.. :-)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp And sometimes a user you helped answers something like "great!" or "THANK YOU!" or better, and you feel warm...

Answer (score 1):

There is one situation where you might see some of that "excess" rep and that is when you lose some rep later that is tied to that particular day.

If someone unaccepts an answer of yours they accepted on that day, or perhaps a question you answered and got points for (again, on that particular day) is deleted (thus deleting all the answers and your points for it), your rep will be recalculated and what was once excess is used to bring you up to the cap again for that day.

Comment: Oooh I see + thank you nice to know if I see another anomolie